# How to create an HDRi environment map with Blender 2.8?

Tags: hdri

I'd like to create a scene in Blender 2.8 and render an HDRi environment texture from it. Is that possible? I expect I'd create a sphere, texture it appropriately, add some distant objects, put the camera at 0,0,0... but how to set up a camera type to record the 360-degree view as a properly formatted HDRi (e.g. equirectangular float EXR)?